# best scripting language\technology to use when building an app that allows to run commands over ssh and via GUI?

Tags: user-interface, shell, scripting, ssh

For my testing environment I want to build a system that can do what I describe below and I would appreciate your feedback on which scripting language\technology is best for doing so.
If you think there is no scripting language suitable for this task, I would appreciate your feedback.
I would also appreciate any suggestions on how you would approach my task.

Thanks.
   RaamEE

Application Description:

1. Display a GUI that will allow me to select a couple of IPs from a DB Query.
2. Open several ssh connections to all of the selected IPs.
3. Allow me to enter a command in the GUI and run it on all machines simultaneously.
4. Optionally, capture the standard output of the command in each of the ssh connections and display it in the GUI or save in a file.

For example I would like to be able to do the following example:

1. Query a DB "which IPs are currently available?". Lets say I get 2 IPs
2. SSH to both IPs simultaneously.
3. Enter in the GUI the command `du -h`
4. Retrieve the Standard output from both SSH connections.
5. Display the result of the `du -h` command on each machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcl/Tk with Expect will meet all your requirements.

Comment: Tcl/Tk indeed sounds as a good enough tool for my task, but say I have the time to invest in learning a stronger technology, would you recommand another tool, besides Tcl/Tk? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check also [Parallel SSH](http://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/), here is article with example: http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/151340 . I hope making GUI for it should be trivial if needed.

Answer (score 0):

not sure about GUI, it can done quite easily using shell, like

```
sql="select ip from table"
cmd="du -h"
for ip in $(mysql -u root -ppassword -h host -N <<<$sql);
do
  ssh $ip $cmd > /tmp/$ip.txt
done
```

**ps:** make sure is the trust-able user to enter the command

Comment: Thanks for the script. The reason I am seeking for a new scripting technology is because I mainly need the GUI. I want to automate tasks like the one I described for other users and give them the option to run and get feedback all in the GUI.

Comment: is not different you store the script into a file and use a crontab to execute it